# Difference between loadings and weights in Partial Least Squares Regression

Tags: r, partial-least-squares, weights

I'm doing PLSR for the data.frame below

I wonder what is the difference between `loadings` and `loading.weights`? Given that they have different signs for some of the predictors (check figures below), which one is recommended to use when discussing the PLSR results?

Using `pls` package

PLSR

```
library(pls)
library(ggrepel)

y <- as.matrix(df[,1])  
x <- as.matrix(df[,2:36])
df_plsr <- mvr(y  ~ x , 
               ncomp = 10, 
               method = "oscorespls" , 
               validation = "LOO",
               scale = T)
```

**Loadings**

```
loadings_df <- as.data.frame(loadings(df_plsr)[,1:4])
names(loadings_df) <- c("comp1", "comp2", "comp3", "comp4")
```

*code for the plot is below*

[image]

**Loading weights**

```
loadingweights_df <- as.data.frame(loading.weights(df_plsr)[,1:4])
names(loadingweights_df) <- c("comp1", "comp2", "comp3", "comp4")
```

*code for the plot is below*

[image]

**DATA**

In this [.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lwgy9ulmyhk9nsl/df.csv?dl=0) file or below

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(dependent = c(0.86397454211987, 0.787954497352421, 
0.659691072486949, 0.946075761583277, 0.728654822779142, 0.62950913750375, 
0.220547032431762, 0.644444993765386, 0.0932051430418795, 0.770186377283592, 
0.649755817096116, 1.2620621832137, 0.813883734861209, 0.756789828278448, 
0.59333732933648), h_f = c(1041.41975308642, 15773.6534246575, 
9657.94383561644, 63956.4219178082, 197778.257534247, 35966.0917808219, 
36205.2424657534, 1846.36849315069, 13306.0657534247, 43568.8849315069, 
10483.9588477366, 4790.59726027397, 2604.7397260274, 8224.63561643836, 
39813.4506849315), h_QuFl = c(326.84540048392, 6557.27843422791, 
3261.10693883351, 24068.3321704268, 65529.9097068129, 15416.1394401651, 
15774.1168214205, 807.867897832351, 5522.27019290237, 16081.754959384, 
4612.86443524532, 1528.19683548948, 872.149503125132, 2895.91238144059, 
16903.29346385), h_BF = c(714.20985306257, 9213.90344104575, 
6396.83689678293, 39897.6782605484, 132174.271350296, 20549.9523406568, 
20431.1256443329, 1038.50059531833, 7778.31571189528, 27484.0175382703, 
5871.0944124913, 3262.40042478449, 1732.59022290227, 5326.69048213606, 
22910.1572210815), h_BFIh = c(0.686, 0.584, 0.662, 0.624, 0.668, 
0.571, 0.564, 0.562, 0.585, 0.631, 0.56, 0.681, 0.665, 0.648, 
0.575), h_Ra = c(6.17674897119342, 8.23551369863014, 7.08599315068493, 
5.4904187128457, 5.67950786402841, 5.41065841802916, 10.8220662100457, 
6.46143835616438, 18.9247260273973, 7.5814924297044, 5.31914951989026, 
7.76993150684932, 6.46958904109589, 7.10945205479452, 5.00932876712329
), h_PET = c(1.81097393689986, 1.65354452054795, 1.73058219178082, 
1.60063065391574, 1.80907762557078, 1.5343526292532, 1.92253424657534, 
1.80904109589041, 1.70986301369863, 1.7879956741168, 1.52829903978052, 
1.71349315068493, 1.59897260273973, 1.75561643835616, 1.62924200913242
), h_ER = c(5.40727023319616, 7.30272260273973, 6.2747602739726, 
4.80876195399328, 4.79026281075596, 4.77028281042863, 9.85849315068493, 
5.66623287671233, 17.9095205479452, 6.6363590483057, 4.69740740740741, 
6.97095890410959, 5.73369863013699, 6.27739726027397, 4.28383561643836
), m_a = c(11.77, 163.19, 135.39, 1261.88, 3191.83, 714.57, 278.69, 
26.58, 57.35, 401.28, 220.41, 53.36, 42.31, 77.35, 744.65), m_MeEl = c(549.25, 
328.67, 451.43, 343.41, 316.31, 362.37, 470.26, 280.56, 521.56, 
308.44, 362.23, 385.66, 312.29, 466.72, 288.97), m_MeSlPe = c(40.55, 
19.53, 28.77, 19.65, 22.82, 19.67, 38.77, 19.97, 39.85, 19.1, 
22.87, 22.55, 17.87, 29.46, 25.77), m_ElRa = c(0.32, 0.36, 0.45, 
0.39, 0.5, 0.42, 0.26, 0.41, 0.45, 0.34, 0.43, 0.47, 0.32, 0.38, 
0.43), m_DrDe = c(1.7, 1.73, 1.57, 1.68, 1.64, 1.65, 1.53, 1.74, 
1.62, 1.7, 1.63, 1.96, 1.81, 1.55, 1.53), c_C2 = c(6.38465773020042, 
9.78985858901589, 1.50356582433208, 7.65339989412654, 5.49752073990677, 
3.90059314867797, 5.9409185818413, 17.4685189240362, 1.3046321051485, 
5.8492626793834, 0, 22.6041793153936, 32.247470774266, 14.1062362886855, 
0.843516522957992), c_C3 = c(54.6485735221962, 47.7105460942601, 
87.9747102844327, 51.8527177042445, 52.9410050371843, 59.9933071920204, 
59.2002531727095, 6.30611865292691, 75.3578079057062, 47.5217195679834, 
73.9175281998161, 33.0000057897949, 17.7895691750417, 50.7102968695948, 
71.2739582196542), c_C4 = c(38.9667687476034, 42.499595316724, 
10.5217238912352, 40.3249893635017, 41.4876095819823, 35.8078469269088, 
34.8588282454492, 76.2253624230368, 23.3375599891453, 46.6290177526332, 
26.0824718001839, 44.3958148948115, 49.9629600506923, 35.1834668417197, 
27.8825252573878), d_D2 = c(6.38465773020042, 2.68799095824262, 
3.83422657879301, 3.10357361725961, 5.72101253575559, 0.582584426668564, 
0.310429629241765, 23.5236369297241, 0, 7.20751236564974, 0, 
16.9040756921581, 11.776860021365, 1.14463243233264, 5.41431731847442
), d_D3 = c(0, 6.00876004990636, 4.60414912318469, 21.2125301554554, 
20.5553248044751, 23.1934190213699, 16.0656101595563, 8.76631382526795, 
0.991353257873467, 2.82722923028608, 33.1101411654781, 1.4597129328763, 
27.0133941457253, 7.18460363621184, 34.038045603972), d_D4 = c(29.812474631149, 
16.9997855063674, 16.9484733602449, 12.2962240035803, 19.4487078537099, 
13.3162195315644, 39.7673906398948, 0, 71.0194979738029, 21.4164343190374, 
23.4607809727846, 5.70504485786588, 5.4888828491522, 11.8151517616597, 
25.9226181415465), d_D5 = c(63.8028676386506, 74.3034634854837, 
74.6131509377774, 63.3876722237047, 54.2749548060594, 62.9077770203972, 
43.8565695713072, 67.7100492450079, 27.9891487683237, 68.5488240850268, 
43.4290778617374, 75.9311665170997, 55.7208629837575, 79.8556121697958, 
34.6250189360071), l_Da = c(22.2987231970424, 37.302281222996, 
0, 15.6888076579869, 15.3143227640784, 7.49552886039105, 9.21111717074486, 
15.6483412661417, 1.09281136009292, 34.6450027695119, 0.180628929489219, 
43.0778604483166, 35.4442243795419, 22.3103188721025, 1.69075281628809
), l_NaCo = c(65.1901939669953, 16.9440437901174, 16.8592486381856, 
10.0217003815836, 16.9178216725931, 7.27861971152794, 66.3473082501395, 
26.9484833920213, 64.9511228483726, 19.8836148068671, 4.13435918931213, 
32.9788279487656, 22.9070497052634, 35.5649600755622, 11.3521194977445
), l_ShBe = c(10.7608030609987, 42.8900057987031, 80.663402529751, 
69.9119944821054, 63.7520715780007, 81.8269148029647, 23.1058374218561, 
52.3253889206384, 32.7228187389004, 43.0244133098626, 90.9194088664656, 
22.7834238897341, 39.6658979608829, 39.4195030936271, 81.3124392127133
), Mr_Co = c(0, 0, 55.1128728093047, 6.51090929661756, 7.75041439460692, 
7.95893058086494, 4.14643495765247, 0, 0, 2.54938917987072, 20.7580709729255, 
0, 0.471612101548274, 0, 11.324878993859), Mr_GRAv = c(35.3896058163273, 
30.7432333308418, 5.10851905044963, 39.847735861398, 30.6826416725748, 
31.7526597888325, 19.4881703291849, 32.2650320691635, 12.3518678893064, 
39.099244961592, 7.05710760397929, 58.8850326871133, 50.9556529985623, 
41.3555074493459, 11.2694297654175), Mr_GREy = c(9.88107227563547, 
27.8058034065098, 7.06352142365074, 6.11279891418493, 13.8435635061977, 
3.3341124261228, 68.1839854780714, 27.5842838556726, 77.3296388036071, 
25.7336688950093, 10.8093669952665, 14.9315696591391, 19.6728001455373, 
3.66489820552796, 1.35155474262874), Mr_Mu = c(0, 27.9788730214221, 
22.4789874821358, 10.9120473953551, 28.3402024501966, 10.44521479672, 
8.18140923509129, 0, 10.1563537553917, 26.509122106797, 13.9141292330255, 
0, 15.2986691974923, 0, 66.5277988300636), Mr_Sa = c(54.7293219080373, 
0, 0, 34.630486683079, 16.1537362551322, 43.2860322394116, 0, 
40.1506840751639, 0, 0, 45.0619898493789, 26.1833976537477, 13.6012655568597, 
54.7388963413616, 4.60393247565709), s_SaLo = c(0, 3.62885344924762, 
49.7156992962877, 22.8742965465896, 16.1037497470103, 26.4108812066677, 
0, 8.76631382526795, 0, 2.28989887729153, 41.204133609971, 1.4597129328763, 
24.7165698755149, 0, 22.1203660572375), s_SiLo = c(68.3924324838086, 
46.7825172630918, 40.2918029150206, 50.9952195120652, 52.4616283965265, 
49.8656534812195, 29.2832265709446, 73.9920650538172, 17.3120134354451, 
47.8438174044157, 35.5069030606913, 69.5515837880942, 62.4089302957283, 
70.6441053507101, 61.3184871234248), s_St = c(9.34306648617202, 
16.9407115250502, 0, 3.02375098621997, 7.49142545780987, 0.739987935905543, 
47.9639272491623, 0, 45.1441255322013, 15.8949013302606, 2.37812587269736, 
4.51166909866183, 1.22573367622539, 1.41402832539501, 0.0517684668983939
), s_sSiLo = c(0, 10.2631744532951, 3.69657384646686, 3.51661128643063, 
5.38382097572785, 4.32919720682223, 17.0908901169596, 0, 26.3981021895912, 
10.2162013196148, 1.64750150735275, 0, 0.3886506275644, 11.6553395492559, 
0.672088258465062), Sr_Li = c(0, 0, 1.70442568792041, 5.71976303452223, 
5.0036595147534, 6.56182424061139, 4.14643495765247, 0, 2.17838680427836, 
2.86071234634266, 3.2464151051141, 0, 0.471612101548274, 0, 0.724170451915613
), Sr_SaLoSi = c(31.4915152861977, 13.0626789594875, 4.58852637794785, 
8.07133532113299, 12.3784892438516, 1.41827358332991, 6.77359973391309, 
28.7019160437988, 0.147389283434159, 20.7639813245479, 4.55174136965654, 
40.9469057406407, 34.0553180610046, 0, 10.1596460774595), Sr_SaCoCoTe = c(0, 
27.9788730214221, 21.8693540906945, 5.7796242808183, 21.9582513650753, 
1.38173157278083, 8.18140923509129, 0, 6.30678806617604, 25.9258663994387, 
4.4796460797524, 0, 15.2986691974923, 0, 48.1840998259004), Sr_SaMu = c(9.88107227563547, 
15.9350047162996, 0, 1.62740092981472, 10.4709347286845, 0, 68.1839854780714, 
27.5842838556726, 77.3296388036071, 20.9061094414991, 0, 14.9315696591391, 
19.6728001455373, 3.66489820552796, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), .Names = c("dependent", 
"h_f", "h_QuFl", "h_BF", "h_BFIh", "h_Ra", "h_PET", "h_ER", "m_a", 
"m_MeEl", "m_MeSlPe", "m_ElRa", "m_DrDe", "c_C2", "c_C3", "c_C4", 
"d_D2", "d_D3", "d_D4", "d_D5", "l_Da", "l_NaCo", "l_ShBe", "Mr_Co", 
"Mr_GRAv", "Mr_GREy", "Mr_Mu", "Mr_Sa", "s_SaLo", "s_SiLo", "s_St", 
"s_sSiLo", "Sr_Li", "Sr_SaLoSi", "Sr_SaCoCoTe", "Sr_SaMu"))
```

Script for plots

```
ggplot(loadings_df, aes(comp1, 
                        comp2))+
  geom_point(size = 0.5)+
  geom_text_repel(aes(label=rownames(loadings_df)), color="blue", size =2.5)+
  ylab("")+xlab("")+#ggtitle("X scores and X Loadings")+
  theme_bw() + #theme(#panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1),
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-0.6,-0.4,-0.2,0,0.2,0.4,0.6
  ))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-0.6,-0.4,-0.2,0,0.2,0.4,0.6
  ))+
  coord_fixed(ylim=c(-0.6, 0.6),xlim=c(-0.6, 0.6))+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 3, color = "blue", size = 0.6)+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = 3, color = "blue", size = 0.6)+
  labs( x = "Component 1",
        y =  "Component 2",
        title = "Loadings")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        plot.title = element_text(#family = "Helvetica", 
          face = "bold", size = 10),
        #axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), 
        axis.text.x=element_text(#angle=35,
          #vjust=1, 
          #hjust=1,
          size = 7 #, face = "bold"
        ),
        axis.text.y=element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0.65, size = 7, margin=margin(10,10,10,5,"pt")),
        axis.title.x = element_text(color="black", #face="bold",
                                    size = 9, margin=margin(10,0,0,0)),
        axis.title.y = element_text(color="black", #face="bold",
                                    size = 9, margin=margin(0,10,0,0)) )



ggplot(loadingweights_df, aes(comp1, 
                        comp2))+
  geom_point(size = 0.5)+
  geom_text_repel(aes(label=rownames(loadingweights_df)), color="blue", size =2.5)+
  ylab("")+xlab("")+#ggtitle("X scores and X Loadings")+
  theme_bw() + #theme(#panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1),
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-0.6,-0.4,-0.2,0,0.2,0.4,0.6
  ))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-0.6,-0.4,-0.2,0,0.2,0.4,0.6
  ))+
  coord_fixed(ylim=c(-0.6, 0.6),xlim=c(-0.6, 0.6))+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 3, color = "blue", size = 0.6)+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = 3, color = "blue", size = 0.6)+
  labs( x = "Component 1",
        y =  "Component 2",
        title = "Weights")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        plot.title = element_text(#family = "Helvetica", 
          face = "bold", size = 10),
        #axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), 
        axis.text.x=element_text(#angle=35,
          #vjust=1, 
          #hjust=1,
          size = 7 #, face = "bold"
        ),
        axis.text.y=element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0.65, size = 7, margin=margin(10,10,10,5,"pt")),
        axis.title.x = element_text(color="black", #face="bold",
                                    size = 9, margin=margin(10,0,0,0)),
        axis.title.y = element_text(color="black", #face="bold",
                                    size = 9, margin=margin(0,10,0,0)) )
```

Comment: Loadings and weights are useful when interpreting individual components. Is it really your purpose? Or are you after interpreting the whole model? If the later is your aim, I would use VIP scores or regression coefficients.

Comment: @theGD
You are right. My purpose is not to interpret individual components. Thanks for your time and help.